# Animation comes off the screen when it receives a positive value reactNative

Tags: react-native, react-animated

Animation in off the screen when it receives a positive value

Why it goes off-screen
For it to stay on screen I have to give it a negative value (e.g. -30)

```js
const animation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

const left = animation.interpolate({
  inputRange: [0, 1],
  outputRange: [0, 30],
});

const onClick = () => {
  Animated.timing(animation, {
    toValue: 30,
    duration: 1000,
    useNativeDriver: true,
  }).start();
};

return (
  <>
    <View>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "red",
          width: 100,
          height: 100,
          transform: [{ translateX: left }],
          margin: 20,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  </>
);

export default App;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
const onClick = () => {
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: 1, //CHANGE THIS TO ONE IN YOUR CODE
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
```

you are interpolating on a value which goes to 30! but your input is 0,to 1!

i hope it helps